# Javascript - function argument

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning Javascript, and bit confused the below usage. These question may be more javaScript than d3 specific.

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/sunburst.html

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
.endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });
```

so,

1. startAngle, endAngle etc takes a function as argument. What is the rationale being the argument a function rather than just a number?
2. In the full code, no where "d" is defined.I see it in almost all of d3 programs. What is "d" for? How is it set or where is it passed?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To your first question:*

The `d3.svg.arc` object is used to create slices inside a pie diagram. Each of these slices needs a different start- and end-angle to be displayed properly.

In `d3.js` you do not pass in both angles for each slice, but provide a function, that takes one argument `d`, which is the corresponding data element for that slice and returns the angles. The same holds for the other parameters set here.

Another advantage is, that a datum can consist of multiple properties and you can decide which property takes which part with respect to the visualization.

*Your second question*

When using a function as a parameter to another function, it is common to use a function expression of the given form. In `d3.js` most functions, that serve as parameters, get passed in one or two parameters themselves (most of the time the part of the data, that needs to be transformed). In your function expression you need (or at least should) name those parameters in order to address them. Most of the time in the example `d` is used as the parametername for the parameter holding the specific data item.

It doesn't need to be defined elsewhere as it is just a normal function parameter. If you wish, you could rewrite it in the following way:

```
function startAngleParam( d ) {
 return d.x;
}

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle( startAngleParam )
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`d` is very clearly passed as the argument to the anonymous function. Presumably these functions *can* take numbers as arguments, or a function for more complex operations (kind of like how `String.replace()` can take a replacement string, OR a function through which to run the result array and that returns the replacement value)

Comment: I see d is passed in anonymous fn. But, coming from other programming language background, if I use d3 library, am I not supposed to pass d (whatever type it is). SO as a user, how I make sure 'startAngle' method get correct d, which has a field x?

Comment: @bsreekanth The startAngle method will call the function you pass to it. If this were a more traditional OO interface, it would be like if the startAngle function received an object with a getAngle method that receives a single parameter (the "d"). You need to make sure that the `d` parameter in the getAngle method matches whatever startAngle will call it with.

Answer (score 1):

1: It's a callback function. The function is not called when you send it as a parameter, instead the function is kept and can be called later, and it can be called over and over whenever needed.

2: The parameter `d` is just a value send into the callback function, which the function uses to produce a result. The identifier name `d` is only defined in the callback function, whenever the function is used the value is just sent into the function as usual.

The value sent into the callback functions is an object that contains the coordinates of the arc. When the coordinates of the arc is changed, the callback functions are called to calculate the other values needed to draw the arc.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but wanted to add to Sirko's excellent answer. He notes:

In d3.js you do not pass in both angles for each slice, but provide a function, that takes one argument `d`, which is the corresponding data element for that slice and returns the angles.

I would add that you may also encounter callbacks of the form `function(d, i) { ... }`. When you see this, `d` refers to the data of the element and `i` refers to its index - the one-letter abbreviations are used by convention but you could call the parameters whatever you want.

Having access to both of these items can be helpful as you iterate through the data. For example, in this tutorial both data and index are used to construct a bar chart: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html